# Micro Services OAuth2.0 Scope implementation

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, client, identityserver4, access-token

What is the best way of implementing such scenario for OAuth 2.0 implementations.

My backend is designed in micro services architecture.

I have client “Mobile” which will make call to ServiceA.

I can add “ScopeA” scope to “Mobile” client which is fine.

Then let's assume tomorrow ServiceA will call ServiceBs authorized endpoint to complete request.

My question is

Which option is right

1. When ServiceA will start call ServiceB I should add ServiceB scope to Mobile client

   - I mean propagate 'Mobile' client access token to all micro services with all required scopes in token.
2. Instead of using Mobile clients access token to call ServiceB, ServiceA should get its own access token to call ServiceB.

For second options we will lost informations like subject information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here. One option is to use the [client credientials flow](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) between ServiceA and ServiceB. In the requests you can pass the user details as normal request parameters.

The advantage with this approach is that even if the user is not logged in, ServiceA can contact ServiceB independently of if the user is logged in or not. For example ServiceA might need to do some background requests to ServiceB.

Another more advanced options is **delegated authentication** that you can read about in [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Delegation-Patterns-for-OAuth-20) article

Comment: delegated authentication is the one I was looking for. Thank you